# Trouble install dropbox on remote server via SSH

Tags: linux, bash, debian, dropbox, wget

I'm trying to install dropbox on a Debian 3.2.46-1 x86_64 system.

The following commands are all successful:

```
mkdir -p ~/bin && bash
wget -qO ~/dropbox.tar.gz "http://www.dropbox.com/download/?plat=lnx.x86_64" && tar -xzf dropbox.tar.gz
wget -qO ~/bin/dropbox.py "http://www.dropbox.com/download?dl=packages/dropbox.py" && chmod 700 ~/bin/dropbox.py
source ~/.bashrc && source ~/.profile
rm -f ~/dropbox.tar.gz
```

However, when I run this command

```
HOME=$HOME/ ~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dropbox/client/main.py", line 13, in <module>
  File "autogen_explicit_imports.py", line 13, in <module>
  File "ui/common/selective_sync.py", line 6, in <module>
  File "arch/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
  File "arch/linux/tracing.py", line 8, in <module>
  File "hard_trace.py", line 6, in <module>
  File "client_api/connection_hub.py", line 21, in <module>
  File "client_api/kv_connection.py", line 23, in <module>
  File "pylinux/__init__.py", line 71, in <module>
  File "cffi/api.py", line 311, in verify
  File "dropbox/overrides.py", line 398, in load_library
  File "cffi/verifier.py", line 69, in load_library
  File "cffi/verifier.py", line 154, in _load_library
  File "cffi/vengine_cpy.py", line 124, in load_library
VerificationError: importing '/media/sdw1/home/mycomputername/pylinux/__pycache__/_cffi__xa0c4f46bx1d95b4de.so': No module named _cffi__xa0c4f46bx1d95b4de
```

Comment: I'm not totally sure, but one line I saw on one set of instructions said, just before running `dropboxd`: *Make sure the LANG environment variable is set to something other than NULL, e.g. en_US.iso88591. If it is NULL, you’ll get a cryptic error.*

Comment: I found something that might be related to your issue: http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=734628

Answer (score 0):

Check out this page:
https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=734628

Try running these commands

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/dropbox/.dropbox-dist
dropbox start -i
```

As stated here:
https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=734628#15